# Changing PC Name not working without running application as administrator

Tags: c#

I am using the below code to programmatically change PC Name,

```
[DllImport("Kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
private static extern bool SetComputerNameEx(COMPUTER_NAME_FORMAT nameType, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPTStr)] string lpBuffer);
private enum COMPUTER_NAME_FORMAT : int
{
   ComputerNameNetBIOS,
   ComputerNameDnsHostname,
   ComputerNameDnsDomain,
   ComputerNameDnsFullyQualified,
   ComputerNamePhysicalNetBIOS,
   ComputerNamePhysicalDnsHostname,
   ComputerNamePhysicalDnsDomain,
   ComputerNamePhysicalDnsFullyQualified,
   ComputerNameMax
}  

SetComputerNameEx(COMPUTER_NAME_FORMAT.ComputerNamePhysicalDnsHostname,"NEWName"); //Call this to change pc name
```

However, this only works if the application is running as administrator.

is there any other way to make this work without running the application as administrator?

I found this [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7646669/rename-computer-programmaticaly-c-sharp-net) but it's not working on me.

Comment: Allowing the modification of the PC name to admins only kinda makes sense from a security's perspective to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need administrator privileges to run this function:

> SetComputerNameEx can set the Computer Name (the first label of the
>   full DNS name) or the primary DNS suffix of the local computer. It
>   cannot set a fully qualified DNS name in one call. If the local
>   computer is a node in a cluster, SetComputerNameEx sets NetBIOS or DNS
>   name of the local computer, not that of the cluster virtual server.
>   **The process that calls the SetComputerNameEx function must have
>   administrator privileges on the local computer**. To compile an
>   application that uses this function, define _WIN32_WINNT as 0x0500 or
>   later. For more information, see Using the Windows Headers.

[source (MSDN)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724931(v=vs.85).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

To rename a PC requires elevated privileges, the same goes for modifying the registry. There's no way around that and its for a good reason, security.